# How to draw a curved triangle with curved inner corners?

Tags: inkscape

I’m pretty new in graphic design (and Inkscape) and can’t figure out how to draw a unfilled rounded corners isosceles triangle.

What I’m trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

Please notice the rounded corners in the inner side of the triangle and the outer corners.

This is what I got so far, but I can’t figure out how to curve the inner part of the corners:

[image]

Comment: Your rounding radius has to be bigger the corner is sharp because the inner radius becomes 0.

Comment: @joojaa Can you explain me how to do it please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably a couple of ways to do this. Here's how I would do it.

1. Draw a triangle with the `Create Stars and Polygons` tool. Apply a thick stroke (about twice the thickness you need), and apply the rounded corners option in the stroke dialog.
2. Click `Path` > `Stroke to Path`
3. With the `Edit Paths by Nodes` tool, select the nodes of the inner path, removing them all, so you are left with one filled outer path.
4. Remove the fill, and set a stroke thinner than before (thin enough to see the inside corners rounded)

[image: Steps of Edit Illustrated]

Answer (score 2):

Draw a triangle. Give to it the wanted wide stroke. You can draw for example a 3 sided polygon holding Ctrl at the same time.

Goto Path > Dynamic offset

Drag the visible node upwards (=**to bigger size**) until you have also round inner corners. That's said already in a comment, but in a short way.

You can resize  the resulted triangle, if it's too big. Resizing without changing the stroke width needs a change in the preferences:

goto Edit > Preferences > Transform, unselect the scaling of strokes.

NOTE: You can't make it arbitarily small because your inner corners will again get sharp as soon as the rounding radius of the outer corners get smaller than the stroke width.